# Does OpenHevc also provide encoder module to encode a yuv stream

Tags: h.264, encoder, hevc

I am working on existing available opensource `HEVC` `encoders`, Right now i got reference HEVC encoder from `Fraunhofer`group and also a optimized  `X265` `encoder` of `multicoreware`. However i also found `OpenHEVC` module my question is that in their readme file they only demonstrate `decoding` of a `HEVC` stream. Does `OpenHEVC` has `encoder` module which can encode a yuv input file in to h265 stream.

Thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have mean this [OpenHEVC](https://github.com/OpenHEVC/openHEVC) than no it doesn't have its own HEVC encoder. And it was said about this in first paragraph of README.md:

> openHEVC is a fork of Libav with only the files needed to decode HEVC
>   content, it was created for research purposes. Most people will not
>   need to use this and should use the libav HEVC decoder available at
>   https://github.com/OpenHEVC/libav instead (see
>   https://libav.org/documentation.html for documentation).

Comment: yes you are right, they are only dealing in Decoder part. thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, OpenHEVC does not have Video encoding.

You can use x265 / FFMPEG, if you want to encode videos in HEVC. 
(x265 is GPL licensed)